# One-to many relationship not working - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, one-to-many

I'm having a problem with creating a one-to-many(or one-to-one?) relationship in entity framework (3.5 I believe).

Example tables/models:

```
Settings:
    SettingsID pk int not null
    SettingsName varchar(250) null
    SettingsTypeID fk int null

SettingsType:
   SettingsTypeID pk int not null
   SettingsTypeName varchar(250)
```

I have a foreign key constraint on `Settings.SettingsTypeID` that references `SettingsType.SettingsTypeID`.

Upon saving a setting (with a chosen `settingstype`) the values save correctly (I have checked the DB to be sure and can see the value of `Setting.SettingsTypeID` update correctly).

However, upon trying to retrieve a `settingType` object based on the chosen `Setting`, e.g.

```
var SettingsType = Setting.SettingsType;
```

`Setting.SettingsType` always comes back `null`?

Am I missing something or?

Answer (score 5):

You need to load the `SettingType` object that is associated with your `Setting` object, using one of the loading patterns described this article on [Loading Related Objects (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx).

I'd suggest using the [`Include` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx), something like this:

```
var setting = (from s in context.Settings.Include("SettingsType") 
               where s.SettingsID == id select s).FirstOrDefault();
```